# CKEditor adds inline nonsense

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm hoping someone else has run into this and has a solution:

I have the CKEditor module (v. 7.x-1.13) installed using ckeditor.js version 4.01 (due to compatibility with Media module). The problem I run into is after I've added content into a field and publish it. After I return to edit the content, CKEditor has added all kinds of "stuff", a ton of inline CSS inside of a paragraph and span, and the letters "BESs" See sample below. Hoping someone can make some sense of this and offer a solution.

```
<p><span style="position:absolute;top:-999px;left:-999px;font-size:300px;width:auto;height:auto;line-height:normal;margin:0;padding:0;font-variant:normal;font-family:adelle,Georgia,'Century Schoolbook L',serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:900;">BESs</span><span style="position:absolute;top:-999px;left:-999px;font-size:300px;width:auto;height:auto;line-height:normal;margin:0;padding:0;font-variant:normal;font-family:ff-tisa-web-pro,arial,'URW Gothic L',sans-serif;font-style:italic;font-weight:700;">BESs</span><span style="position:absolute;top:-999px;left:-999px;font-size:300px;width:auto;height:auto;line-height:normal;margin:0;padding:0;font-variant:normal;font-family:proxima-nova,Georgia,'Century Schoolbook L',serif;font-style:italic;font-weight:800;">BESs</span></p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bug in WebKit/Blink http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998. I don't know what you did with your text so I can't help more. But if it does not happen within Firefox or IE, then it is definitely that bug.